# Flutter crashlytics . #00 abs c36711e3 virt 003ae1e3 _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x513a3 error

Tags: flutter, crashlytics

**I have this bug in crashlytics
**
. #00 abs c36711e3 virt 003ae1e3 _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x513a3

and there is no line numbere found for the the issue.

I searched for this bug but no one  write about it.

```
0
 
Unsafe.java
`sun.misc.Unsafe.park
1
 
LockSupport.java - Line 190
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park + 190
2
 
AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java - Line 2067
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await + 2067
3
 
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java - Line 1120
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take + 1120
4
 
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java - Line 849
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take + 849
5
 
ThreadPoolExecutor.java - Line 1092
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask + 1092
6
 
ThreadPoolExecutor.java - Line 1152
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1152
7
 
ThreadPoolExecutor.java - Line 641
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 641
8
 
Thread.java - Line 923`
```